# wxWidgets cross compilation from linux to windows - what does "--host=" mean?

Tags: linux, windows, wxwidgets, cross-compiling

I'm cross compiling wxWidgets using [that tutorial](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_wxWidgets_Applications_on_Linux#wxWidgets_cross-build). Could anyone explain me what --host=i586-mingw32msvc does?
I know that prefix give the information where cross-compiler is. However, I compiled minGW from source manually, because then I can use the newest GCC so I can't only copy&paste.
Prefix should be  prefix=/usr/local/i386-mingw32 because there is my cross-compiler. And what about host?
I use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS AMD64 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--host` is a typical `./configure` option that specifies the "host" system for the program to run on, i.e. the configuration that you will be compiling for.

In other words, `--host` activates cross-compiling behaviour if you specify a host that is not the same as your build machine.

The format of the `host` spec differs occasionally between platforms, but it generally takes the form

```
processorfamily-osfamily[-osversion][-abi]
```

Comment: f.e. --host=name
The name must be the same like cross-compiler's folder? Or even completely "random" ? Because I don't know if it uses prefix and then specify compiler name ... or what?

Comment: @TomaszHamerla: Honestly, you're better off just looking it up. Often, but not always, it will be the prefix that the compiler binaries use (e.g. you may have a compiler called `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc`). But, if you don't, you may just want to look up what `host=` to use.

Comment: My compiler prefix is i386-mingw32 - I use it and compiling simple console apps statically works. However, where could I definitely check it? :)

Comment: If your compiler prefix is `i386-mingw32` then you should try `--host=i386-mingw32` and see if that works. (MinGW website itself discourages appending `msvc` to the `--host` name: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW).

Comment: So I'll try tomorrow. If any problem occurs, I'll write again.

Comment: Everything OK. However, there is the new problem with the linking the library, if you could look at it:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272822/c-wxwidgets-codeblocks-cross-compiling-linking-errors-during-custom-project