# C++ wxWidgets Code::Blocks cross-compiling linking errors during custom project "normal" compilation and C++11 enabled

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets, cross-compiling, static-linking

I use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS AMD64.
In this way I compiled wxWidgets 3.0.1 with the help of [that tutorial](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_wxWidgets_Applications_on_Linux) (I changed global compiler settings, not the target ones - my target to Win name is Windows ):

```
/home/tomasz/Pobrane/src/wxWidgets-3.0.1/configure prefix=/usr/local/i386-mingw32 --host=i386-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux --enable-unicode --disable-shared --disable-debug --with-msw --enable-stl
```

Then i used make -j3 and install make. Everything - OK.
However, there is the problem with linking:

```
obj/Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `wxEntry(HINSTANCE__*, HINSTANCE__*, char*, int)'
obj/Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to wxAppConsoleBase::CheckBuildOptions(char const*, char const*)'
```

I think that the problem is connected with wx/app.h because when I disabled it, there weren't errors like the ones.

The whole log:

```
-------------- Build: Windows in Symulator Kostek (compiler: MingW32 Compiler)---------------

i386-mingw32-g++  -I/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/ -c "/home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.cpp" -o obj/Windows/panels.o
i386-mingw32-g++ -L/usr/local/i386-mingw32/lib/ -o "bin/Windows/Symulator Kostek.exe" obj/Windows/main.o obj/Windows/main_frame.o obj/Windows/panels.o    
In file included from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/msw/gccpriv.h:61:0,
                 from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/platform.h:456,
                 from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/defs.h:27,
                 from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/event.h:14,
                 from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/window.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/panel.h:19,
                 from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.h:4,
                 from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.cpp:1:
/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/w32api.h:27:2: warning: #warning WARNING - The w32api.h header file is deprecated and will be removed. [-Wcpp]
 #warning WARNING - The w32api.h header file is deprecated and will be removed.
  ^
obj/Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `wxEntry(HINSTANCE__*, HINSTANCE__*, char*, int)'
obj/Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `wxAppConsoleBase::CheckBuildOptions(char const*, char const*)'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i386-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../i386-mingw32/bin/ld: obj/Windows/main.o: zły adres przemieszczenia 0xf w sekcji `.text$_ZN8wxString7ImplStrEPKw[__ZN8wxString7ImplStrEPKw]'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i386-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../i386-mingw32/bin/ld: final link failed: Nieprawidłowa operacja
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
```

And when I try to use C++11 (the reason why I compiled MinGW manually because of the old compiler in repository):

```
/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/io.h:301:14: error: ‘off64_t’ does not name a type
/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/io.h:302:14: error: ‘off64_t’ does not name a type  
/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/wxcrtbase.h:680:68: error: ‘wcsdup’ was not declared in this scope
```

And the whole log:

```
-------------- Build: Windows in Symulator Kostek (compiler: MingW32 Compiler)---------------

    i386-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/ -c "/home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.cpp" -o obj/Windows/panels.o
    i386-mingw32-g++ -L/usr/local/i386-mingw32/lib/ -o "bin/Windows/Symulator Kostek.exe" obj/Windows/main.o obj/Windows/main_frame.o obj/Windows/panels.o    
    In file included from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/msw/gccpriv.h:61:0,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/platform.h:456,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/defs.h:27,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/event.h:14,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/window.h:18,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/panel.h:19,
                     from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.h:4,
                     from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.cpp:1:
    /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/w32api.h:27:2: warning: #warning WARNING - The w32api.h header file is deprecated and will be removed. [-Wcpp]
     #warning WARNING - The w32api.h header file is deprecated and will be removed.
      ^
    In file included from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/wxcrtbase.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/string.h:45,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/memory.h:15,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/object.h:19,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/event.h:16,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/window.h:18,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/panel.h:19,
                     from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.h:4,
                     from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.cpp:1:
    /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/io.h:301:14: error: ‘off64_t’ does not name a type
     __CRT_INLINE off64_t lseek64 (int, off64_t, int);
                  ^
    /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/io.h:302:14: error: ‘off64_t’ does not name a type
     __CRT_INLINE off64_t lseek64 (int fd, off64_t offset, int whence) {
                  ^
    In file included from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/string.h:45:0,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/memory.h:15,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/object.h:19,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/event.h:16,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/window.h:18,
                     from /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/panel.h:19,
                     from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.h:4,
                     from /home/tomasz/Dropbox/Programy/Linux/wxWidgets/Symulator Kostek/panels.cpp:1:
    /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/wxcrtbase.h: In function ‘wchar_t* wxStrdup(const wchar_t*)’:
    /usr/local/i386-mingw32/include/wx/wxcrtbase.h:680:68: error: ‘wcsdup’ was not declared in this scope
     inline wchar_t* wxStrdup(const wchar_t *s) { return wxCRT_StrdupW(s); }
                                                                        ^
    Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))
    3 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))
```

Comment: Did you see this: http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=34374

Comment: I think that problem could be somewhere there ... however I don't know what the author of the solution meant... copy files? Or what?

Comment: looks like outdated symbols

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely separate problems here:

1. The link errors are just due to not linking with wxWidgets libraries at all -- your command line doesn't mention them anywhere. Use the output of `wx-config --libs` in your makefile.
2. The C++11 compilation problems are due to compiling wxWidgets without C++11 support. With g++ you can't use C++11 in your application without using it in the library or vice versa as C++98 and C++11 are *not* ABI-compatible. Rebuild the library with `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11` to fix this.

Comment: 1->You mean adding it to 'resource compiler' line in compiler options or just linker optional settings?  
2->I cross compile the library. You mean using configure option?
I re-installed my system to solve several problems and make sure that there is no problem somewhere there.  
Thanks for answer.

Comment: I mean linker options, you are not linking with wx at all right now. And cross-compiling or not doesn't matter here, you must [cross-]compile wxWidgets with `-std=c++11` if you want to use it with your code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll compile my project tomorrow.